# How can i get default locale parameter value from config.yml Symfon 2x

Tags: symfony

How can i get default locale parameter value from config.yml Symfon 2x

```
$this->container->getParameter('default_locale');
```

NOT WORKING!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It takes the value from parameters.yml :

```
$this->container->getParameter('locale');
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in Symfony3 the `default_locale` set using:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

is available as `kernel.default_locale` parameter in a controller:

```
$this->getParameter('kernel.default_locale');
```

See: https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L91

Answer (score 2):

The key name is "kernel.default_locale".

If you want to see all parameters of config you can var_dump the ParameterBag from the container:

```
$this->container->getParameters();
```

Comment: I like this way cause has no dependency if user use or not the value from parameter.yml. This way gets the real value passed to Kernel instance

Answer (score 1):

In controller you have access for parameters in `parameters.yml` via

`$this->container->getParameter('parameter_name');`

But if you wanna use paramater from `parameters.yml` (in fact `config.yml`) outside controller you have to inject this parameter. More info about types of Dependency Injection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html